# Как исключить определенные файлы из обработки в gulp

Tags: gulp4

**Resource:**

```
function css() {

    return  gulp.src([ './node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css', './src/css/block-01.less'])
                .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
                .pipe(less())
                .pipe(gcmq())
                .pipe(concat('styles.css')) // на этой строке почему-то normalize.css объединяется в файл styles.css 
                .pipe(autoprefixer({
                  browsers: ['> 0.1%'],
                  cascade: false
                  }))
               .pipe(clean({level: 2}))
                .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
                .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/css/'))
                .pipe(browserSync.stream());

}
```

**Question:**

Есть ли  в gulp исключать определенные количество файлов, дабы они собирались отдельно (на данном примере). Когда запускаю сборщик gulp, то сборщик полностью собирает все в кучу, то что мне не хочется. Как сделать, чтобы один был независим(или несколько файлов), а остальные сконкатенировались??

Используется версия `gulp: 4.0.2`

Comment: По поводу строки. вы делаете concat которые и объединяет все файлы в один

Comment: да, объединяю, а если какие-то файлы нужно просто проигнорировать, разнести их отдельно? где-то читал  предлагают создать отдельный таск

Comment: Вы можете создать несколько тасков и вызывать 2 таска в одном